# PHP Authorization fail when post in google moment with plusapi

Tags: php, codeigniter, authorization, google-api-php-client

I was trying to made a post for google plus moment in php, i using below code, but when trying to post i am getting authorization error, I am doing with codeignitter

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
include_once 'base_controller.php';

class Gp_auth extends Base_controller {

    private $_gp_client;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library('googleplus');
    $this->_gp_client = $this->googleplus->client;
}

public function index() {
    if ($this->input->get_post('code')) {
        try {
            $this->_gp_client->authenticate($this->input->get_post('code'));
            $access_token = $this->_gp_client->getAccessToken();
            $this->session->set_userdata('access_token', $access_token);
            redirect('/gp_auth/me');
        } catch (Google_Auth_Exception $e) {
            _print($e);
        }
    } else {
        $this->_gp_client->addScope(array(
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write'
        ));

        $this->_gp_client->setRequestVisibleActions('http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity');

        try {
            echo anchor($this->_gp_client->createAuthUrl(), 'Conect Me');
        } catch (Google_Auth_Exception $e) {
            _print($e);
        }
    }
}

public function me() {
    try {
        $this->_gp_client->setAccessToken($this->session->userdata('access_token'));
        $response = $this->googleplus->plus->people->get('me');
        _print($response->id);
        $post_data = array(
            'gp_id' => $response->id,
            'gp_access_token' => $this->session->userdata('access_token'),
            'post_body' => 'Hello Google moment',
            'post_attachment' => ''
        );
        $this->load->library('sns_post');
        echo $this->sns_post->gp_post($post_data);

    } catch (Google_Auth_Exception $e) {
        _print($e);
    }
}
```

}

index function was for authentication
and  'me' function for for post moment

and below code for library code of moment post , which is called from me function

```
public function gp_post($post_data) {
    $this->_CI->load->library('googleplus');
    _print($post_data['gp_access_token']);
    $this->_CI->googleplus->client->setAccessToken($post_data['gp_access_token']);
    $this->_CI->googleplus->client->setRequestVisibleActions('http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity');

    $this->_CI->googleplus->item_scope->setId($post_data['gp_id']);
    $this->_CI->googleplus->item_scope->setType("http://schema.google.com/AddAction");
    $this->_CI->googleplus->item_scope->setName("The Google+ Platform");
    $this->_CI->googleplus->item_scope->setDescription($post_data['post_body']);
    if (!empty($post_data['post_attachment'])) {
        $this->_CI->googleplus->item_scope->setImage($post_data['post_attachment']);
    }
    $this->_CI->googleplus->moment_body->setTarget($this->_CI->googleplus->item_scope);

    // Execute the request
    try {
        $momentResult = $this->_CI->googleplus->plus->moments->insert('me', 'vault', $this->_CI->googleplus->moment_body);
        _print($momentResult);
    } catch (Google_Auth_Exception $e) {
        _print($e);
    } catch (Google_Service_Exception $servic_exception) {
        _print($servic_exception);
    }


    if ($response->meta->status == 201) {
        return $response->response->id;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I am also facing same problem.

Comment: What is the specific error that you're getting?

Comment: What are the library you're using? could you post the link to it?

Comment: i am using https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client library, slightly modify for codeingnitter

Comment: Can you post error? It will give more visibility to understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have get authorization error because of following reason -

1. Not setting email id & project name using developer console link `APIs & Auth->Consent Screen`.
2. You are calling deprecated API `$this->_CI->googleplus->item_scope->setId($post_data['gp_id']);`. To Call this you have to use this class `new Google_Service_Plus_ItemScope();`
3. `$this->_CI->googleplus->moment_body->setTarget($this->_CI->googleplus->item_scope);` .To call this method you have to use this class `new Google_Service_Plus_Moment()`;
4. I have setup demo code in git for you. [Google-Plus-API-Codeigniter-Starter](https://github.com/rajeshujade/google-plus-api-codeigniter-starter). You can use same code to start with. I have provided detailed instruction in git repository too.
5. You have to Register your application using Google Console Settings as below:

   - Go to [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
   - Create Project
   - To Get ***Google+ API*** Access go to: APIs & Auth->APIs -> enable Google+ API
   - To Get ***client_id & client_secret*** go to: APIs & Auth->Credentials->Create new Client ID
   - To Get ***api_key*** go to: APIs & Auth->Credentials->Create New Key->Browser key
   - To Get ***application_name*** go to: APIs & Auth->Consent Screen

     1. Set Email Address
     2. Product Name

**Note:** Ensure you have get all the required access from google as mentioned in point **5**

**Conclustion:** You are using Latest google-api-php-client client. And trying to call method in an older way. Hence its not working.

Comment: the github repository of googleplusapi codeignitter using depreceated methods, thats not work now, i already tested these methods. 

I also follow the second link u give before, its not working, and i am using the same library u can see in my comments before

Comment: @KishorDgupta I have changed the answer. Also set the git repo for you.Check this link https://github.com/rajeshujade/google-plus-api-codeigniter-starter

Comment: ok, let me implement these, i will let u know the results, thanks for the help

Comment: hi, i tried with these, exact same result, authnecation failed when tried to post. i directly use ur project, also use right credential from app console dashboard, its not working

Comment: Can you post error stack trace?Is it possible for you to give google configurations?

Comment: Try to configure/cross verify google configuration as mentioned in point 5

Comment: You can get configuration reference from git README file.I am sure you are missing google configuration somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, however conclusion is only app activity could posted via app and it keep hidden as activity not as wall post, not the outcome i hoped, but fianlly get the closure abt what really happening, google plus api need many improvements comapre to fb, twitter, linkedin nd tumbler

Comment: @KishorDgupta have you try to use https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities/insert

Comment: tried, but the post will kept hidden in activities of user profile, not shown as timeline post which i inteded, also google is switching from login with googleplus to login with google , they are not going to give googleplus any priority now, So we thought we should also move on